# For which values of $x \in I$ is $(f_n)$ differentiable term by term?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

> Let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}e^{-nx}$ on $x\in[0,1] =I$.
>
> 1. Discuss the pointwise and uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ on $I$.
> 2. For which values of $x \in I$ is $(f_n)$ differentiable term by term?

My attempt:

> 1.
>
> **Pointwise Convergence:**
>
> $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x \in I$.
>
> Hence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$ on $I$.
>
> **Uniform Convergence:**
>
> $\|f_n-0\| = \sup \bigg\{\bigg|\frac{1}{n}e^{-nx} \bigg| : x \in [0,1] \bigg\} = \bigg| \frac{1}{n} \bigg| = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
>
> Hence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f(x) = 0$ on $I$.

Is this correct?

> 2.
>
> This is the question which I am stuck at.
>
> I know that, in order for $(f_n)$ to be term by term differentiable
>
> - $(f_n)$ must converge pointwise
> - $f'_n$ must be continuous and
> - $(f'_n)$ must converge uniformly.
>
> However, this does not occur on the entire interval $I = [0,1]$. Can anyone please show me how I can go about finding the the values of $x$ in $I$ for which this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'_n(x)=e^{-nx}$ is a geometric series that converges uniformly on $[a,1]$ for $0<a<1$. It follows that $\{f_n\}$ is differentiable term by term on $(0,1]$.